# Pause function won't pause mt game

Tags: python, pygame

So I been trying make my Pause function work ever since I moved my start screen away form my game loop to make my crash function work but i started to get a problem witch is making my pause function not work.

https://gyazo.com/c814f08961bf1738b547d0949f9b2f87

the video dose not show much but I am pressing my button that make's my game pause but it is not show the  pause game menu, I don't really know why. I have tried to moved my pause function all the way up with my start screen but that did not work to, also I have tried putting it on the main loop but that did not work to.

this is my pause function

```
pause = False

        

    def quitgame():
        pygame.quit()

    def unpause():
        global pause
        pause = False
        
    def paused():
        
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        

        button("Can Run",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,unpause)
        button("Sit",300,350,100,50,red,darkred,quitgame)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

this is my full code

```
import pygame,time
pygame.init()

#screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

fps = (10)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

darkred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

green = (0,255,0)

red = (255,0,0)

black = (0,0,0)
    
black = (0,0,0)
# START SCREEN
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',55)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    main_loop()
    time.sleep(1)


    
    

def crash():
    message_display('NOOB YOU DED')

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()

    
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',60)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("ULTIMATE DASH", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Run!",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,main_loop)
        button("Sit!",300,350,100,50,red,darkred,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
            
def main_loop():
    global pause   

    #set name
    pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")

    bg = pygame.image.load("leafy_background.jpg")
    mad1 = pygame.image.load("MAD1.png")
    mad2 = pygame.image.load("MAD2.png")
    happy1 = pygame.image.load("happytext1.png")
    happy2 = pygame.image.load("happytext2.png")
    happy3 = pygame.image.load("happytext3.png")
    hapad = pygame.image.load("happymadtext1.png")
    end =  pygame.image.load("endtext1.png")
    ss1 = pygame.image.load("Coin2.png")
    ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(ss1,(ss1.get_width()//12,ss1.get_height()//12))
    ss2 = pygame.image.load("HP.png")
    ss2 = pygame.transform.scale(ss2,(ss2.get_width()//5,ss2.get_height()//5))
    ff = pygame.image.load("Pbut.png")
    ff = pygame.transform.scale(ff,(ff.get_width()//4,ff.get_height()//4))


# PLAYER        
    class player:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.speed = 6
            self.isJump = False
            self.JumpCount = 10
            self.fall = 0
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Me1.png")
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//8,self.ss1.get_height()//8))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            player_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # the player_image << put your image like self.image
            player_rect.centerx += +2 # 10 is just an example
            player_rect.centery += -6# 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ss1, player_rect) # change the player_image to your image like self.image

# PLATFORM
    class platform:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Dirt.png")
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//7,self.ss1.get_height()//7))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            platform_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # the player_image << put your image like self.image
            platform_rect.centerx += +2 # 10 is just an example
            platform_rect.centery += -3# 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ss1, platform_rect)

# WALL
    class wall:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        

# SPIKE
    class spike:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Spike.png")
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//3))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            spike_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # the player_image << put your image like self.image
            spike_rect.centerx += +10 # 10 is just an example
            spike_rect.centery += -16# 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ss1, spike_rect)


# ICE
    class ice:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.speed = 7
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("ice.png")
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//1,self.ss1.get_height()//1))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
           

            
            fall_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            fall_rect.centery += 2
            fall_rect.centerx += 1
            window.blit(self.ss1, fall_rect)


# COIN
    class coin:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y= y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Coin2.png")
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//10,self.ss1.get_height()//10))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            coin_rect  = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            coin_rect.centery -= 1
            coin_rect.centerx -= 1
            window.blit(self.ss1,coin_rect)

#RECTA
    class recta:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)

#PIKW
    class pike:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Spike2.png")
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//3))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            pike_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # the player_image << put your image lik self.image
            pike_rect.centerx += +10 # 10 is just an example
            pike_rect.centery += -12# 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ss1, pike_rect)

#LIVE
    class live:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("HP.png")
            self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//4,self.ss1.get_height()//4))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            pike_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)  # the player_image << put your image lik self.image
            pike_rect.centerx += -5 # 10 is just an example
            pike_rect.centery += -30# 15 is just an example
            window.blit(self.ss1, pike_rect)       




    #draw player
    white = (255,255,255)

    darkred = (200,0,0)

    darkgreen = (0,200,0)

    green = (0,255,0)

    red = (255,0,0)

    black = (0,0,0)
    
    #PLAYER1
    player1 = player(0,400,40,40,white)

    #PLATFORMS
    platform1 = platform(0,0,400000,30,black)
    platform2 = platform(0,470,400000,30,black)

    #WALLS
    wall1 = wall(0,0,40000,30,black)
    wall2 = wall(0,470,40000,30,black)

    #SPIKES
    spike1 = spike(400,436,15,35,white)
    spike2 = spike(200,436,15,35,white)

    #ICES
    ice1 = ice(13250,70,25,95,white)
    ice2 = ice(13300,70,25,95,white)
    ice3 = ice(13350,70,25,95,white)
    ice4 = ice(13400,70,25,95,white)

    #COINS
    coin1 = coin(100,200,35,50,white)
    coin2 = coin(100,200,35,50,white)

    #RECTAS
    recta1 = recta(13200,0,600,600,white)
    recta2 = recta(34000,0,400,600,white)
    recta3 = recta(34450,0,400,600,white)
    recta4 = recta(43000,0,400,600,white)
    recta5 = recta(43450,0,400,600,white)
    recta6 = recta(43900,0,400,600,white)
    recta7 = recta(44250,0,500,600,white)
    recta8 = recta(45000,0,500,600,white)
    recta9 = recta(100,100,50,50,white)

    #PIKES
    pike1 = pike(799,799,1,1,white)
    pike2 = pike(799,799,1,1,white)

    live1 = live(43000,350,30,30,white)
    live2 = live(900,900,1,1,white)

    # LIST
    platforms = [platform1,platform2]
    walls = [wall1,wall2]
    spikes = [spike1,spike2]
    ices = [ice1,ice2,ice3,ice4]
    coins = [coin1,coin2]
    rectas = [recta1,recta2,recta3,recta4,recta5,recta6,recta7,recta8]
    pikes = [pike1,pike2]
    lives = [live1,live2]


    # MY GAME AND HOW IT LOOKS LIKE
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    level = [
    "                                                                                                                                                                                                             ",
    "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ",
    "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ",
    "                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ",
    "                                                                                                                                                                cccc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             c  c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            psssss               ",
    "                                                                                                                                                                c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             c  p  p  pssss                                                                                          p  p  p  p                                                                                                                              p                                                     ",
    "                                                                                                               y   y       y   y                                c                                                                                                                              c  c   c                                                                              c     c             y                                                                       c   c  c     p                                                                                                    p                                                                                                                       cccccccccc  p                                               ",
    "                                                                                  cc                             c  c  c  c  c                                  cccc                                                                     c   c  c                 c  c   c                                                                                                              p  p  p     c                                                                       c  p  p  p  p  p                                                                 cccccc                    p  p  p  p                                                                                                                          p  p  p  p                                                                                ",                        
    "                                                    c  c  c  c                      c                                                            y   y          c                  c   c  c  c        y  y  y                            c   c  c                                            p  p  p  p    c                   y        y      y  y  y          yy   yy         c    p           p  p  p    c            c                            y   y   y             p                 p                                                              cccccc   y             p              p                                                                     y  y  y  y  y                                  p              p                               y   y                           ",
    "                             p        y           p  p  p  p  p                ccccccc                         p  p  p  p  p  p  p          p                   c               p   y   y   y                                            ccccc  c               p  p  p  p     c          p   ss ss ss   p                                                                        p                      p  p  p         p                                            c  p                       p                                            p              cccccc              p                    psssss                                                       p                                                 p                    pssss                    p                            ",
    "               c  c       p      c    c     k  p                   yyyyyyy          c      yy   yyyy        p                        k   p                      cccc          p                         c  c      yyyyyy    yyyyyyy      c   c  c            p              p          p                   s p    c    c         yyyyy          c   c       c c c c c c       cp                                      p    ss   yyyyyyy   yyyyyyy       c   c         p                             p              y    y    y             p     p    k      cccccc           p                                                           y   y   y   y   y     p                       c             k           p                    yyyyyyyy   yyyyyyy       p                                                              ",
    "             s  s  s    p   ssss  c s  s     p    s s s s s s s      c c c        cc     s c  sc  c  s   p      s  s  s  s  s  s  s   p   s s    s   s   s  s  s  s  s  s  p           s   s k  s     s  s  s             s          s   c   c  c     k   p     s s s s s s s s     p     s s s s s s s s       s  s  s  s   k s   c c  s     s  s  s       p cs    s       p      s  s  s  s s s s s s s s s s    p            c c  c  s  c  c   s   s   s   s k  p     s s s s s s s s s s s ss      ccccccc   s    s    s      s  s  s           s  s  s  cccccc   s    p     s s s s s s s s s s s                                  s   s   s   s   s    p           s  s  s  s  s  c  s  s  s  s  s   s   p     sssssssssss                s         s  p                                                                    ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",] 


    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = platform(ix*57, iy*41.2, 50,20,(255, 255, 255))
                platforms.append(new_platforms)
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "s":
                new_spikes = spike(ix*57, iy*39.7, 15, 35,(255, 255, 255))
                spikes.append(new_spikes)
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "c":
                new_coins = coin(ix*57, iy*39.7, 15, 55,(255, 255, 255))
                coins.append(new_coins)
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):            
            if col == "y":
                new_pikes = pike(ix*57, iy*39.7, 15, 30,(255, 255, 255))
                pikes.append(new_pikes)

    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):            
            if col == "k":
                new_lives = live(ix*57, iy*39.7, 30, 30,(255, 255, 255))
                lives.append(new_lives)


# PAUSE FUNCTION
        
    pause = False

        

    def quitgame():
        pygame.quit()

    def unpause():
        global pause
        pause = False
        
    def paused():
        
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        

        button("Can Run",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,unpause)
        button("Sit",300,350,100,50,red,darkred,quitgame)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


        
    
    






    
    #redraw
    def redrawwindow():
        window.fill((0,0,0))
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))
        

                    
        

    #draw olayer
        player1.draw()
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.draw()
        for wall in walls:
            wall.draw()
        for ice in ices:
            ice.draw()
        for recta in rectas:
            recta.draw()
        recta9.draw()


     # the score draw it on the screen
        window.blit(text,textRect)
        window.blit(talk,talkRect)

        for spike in spikes:
            spike.draw()
        for coin in coins:
            coin.draw()
        for pike in pikes:
            pike.draw()
        for live in lives:
            live.draw()



    #THE FONT AND NAMES
    font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
    score = 0
    text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(0,0,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((100,50))


    font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
    deaths = 5
    talk = font.render(" = "+str(deaths),True,(0,0,0))
    talkRect = talk.get_rect()
    talkRect.center = ((100,90))

    fps = (30)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()



    #MAIN LOOP
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                
    #     LIVES AND SPIKE
        lstdel = []
        for i,spk in enumerate(spikes):
            if spk.rect.left > 500 or spk.rect.left < 0: continue  # off screen
            if player1.rect.colliderect(spk.rect):
                if deaths > 0:
                    deaths -= 1
                    talk = font.render(" = "+str(deaths),True,(0,0,0))
                    talkRect.center = ((100,90))
                    lstdel.append(i)
        for i in lstdel[::-1]:
            del spikes[i]  #delete from end
      
        lstdel = []
        for i,pk in enumerate(pikes):
            if pk.rect.left > 500 or pk.rect.left < 0: continue  # off screen
            if player1.rect.colliderect(pk.rect):
                if deaths > 0:
                    deaths -= 1
                    talk = font.render(" = "+str(deaths),True,(0,0,0))
                    talkRect.center = ((100,90))
                    lstdel.append(i)
        for i in lstdel[::-1]:
            del pikes[i]  #delete from end
      
        lstdel = []
        for i, lv in enumerate(lives):
            if lv.rect.left > 500 or lv.rect.left < 0: continue  # off screen
            if player1.rect.colliderect(lv.rect):
                if deaths > 0:
                    deaths += 1
                    talk = font.render(" = "+str(deaths),True,(0,0,0))
                    talkRect.center = ((100,90))
                    lstdel.append(i)
        for i in lstdel[::-1]:
            del lives[i]
            
        #ADDING TO COIN +1
        for coin in coins:
            for one in range(len(coins)-1,-1,-1):
                if player1.rect.colliderect(coins[one].rect):
                    del coins[one]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(0,0,0))
                    textRect.center = ((100,50))

        

        if deaths < 1:
            crash()
    

            
        #moving keys
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


        player1.x += player1.speed

        # ANOTHER PART OF PAUSE 
        if keys[pygame.K_p]:
            pause = True
            paused()

        #WHAT MAKES ICEBURG FALL
        for ice in ices:
            if player1.rect.colliderect(recta1.rect):
                ice.y += 3


            


        
        #WHAT MAKES EVEYTHING NOT FOLLOW THE PLAYER    
        if player1.x > 250:
            player1.x -= player1.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x -= player1.speed
            for spike in spikes:
                spike.x -= player1.speed
            for ice in ices:
                ice.x -= player1.speed
            for recta in rectas:
                recta.x -= player1.speed
            for pike in pikes:
                pike.x -= player1.speed
            for coin in coins:
                coin.x -= player1.speed
            for live in lives:
                live.x -= player1.speed



         #FALLING   
        if not player1.isJump:
            player1.y += player1.fall
            player1.fall += 1
            player1.isJump = False



                
            #COLLIDE WITH PLATFORM
            collide = False
            for platform in platforms:
                if player1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.y = platform.rect.top - player1.height + 1
                    if player1.rect.right > platform.rect.left and player1.rect.left < platform.rect.left - player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.left - player1.width
                    if player1.rect.left < platform.rect.right and player1.rect.right > platform.rect.right + player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.right
                                  

                #COLLIDE
                if player1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.JumpCount = 8
                    player1.y = 500 - player1.height

                    
            #KEY FOR SPACEBAR
            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    player1.isJump = True
                player1.fall = 0


        #JUMP COUNT
        else:
            if player1.JumpCount >= 0:
                player1.y -= (player1.JumpCount*abs(player1.JumpCount))*0.2
                player1.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                player1.JumpCount = 10
                player1.isJump = False
            


    #END OF GAME            
        redrawwindow()
        

        # TEXT THAT CORATOR IS SAYING
        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta2):
            window.blit(mad1,(100,170))
            
        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta3):
            window.blit(mad2,(100,170))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta4):
            window.blit(happy1,(100,100))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta5):
            window.blit(happy2,(100,100))    

        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta6):
            window.blit(happy3,(100,100))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta7):
            window.blit(hapad,(100,100))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(recta8):
            window.blit(end,(100,100))

        window.blit(ss1,(30,25))
        
        window.blit(ss2,(-40,-20))

        window.blit(ff,(400,10))
            
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    unpause()
game_intro()
main_loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pause` function is being called, but the `while` loop is ignored.

This is because your indents are wrong. The `while` loop is not part of the `pause` function. The loop is run at the start of the game and does nothing since `pause` is False.

Make this change:

```
def paused():
    
    ..........

    while pause:  # must be indented to be part of paused()
                
        ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

The while paused loop is not inside of the paused function.
When the program reaches the loop, it skipps it because pause = False,and never returns to it because pause is not in the function